# FileNotFoundException (sunrsasing.jar)

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception

I'm translating an api from php to java, i've wrote the following code to emulate sha1 method from php.
The problem is that when it creates the new formatter object, I get a FileNotFoundException, debugging I found out that it couldn't find "sunrsasing.jar", looking through stackoverflow I found:

> which I'm reading so that before JDK5, it was in a separate jar provided by sun that you mentioned. After that, it was distributed as part of JDK, and not as a separate jar.
>   Blockquote

So my question is, is there any way i can fix the error other than copy & paste the jar from some other source?
If not, where can I find it?

```
private static String encryptPassword(String password)
{
    String sha1 = "";
    try
    {
        MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        crypt.reset();
        crypt.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        sha1 = byteToHex(crypt.digest());
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sha1;
}



private static String byteToHex(final byte[] hash)
{
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    for (byte b : hash)
    {
        formatter.format("%02x", b);
    }
    String result = formatter.toString();
    formatter.close();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Formatter` is available since Java 5, so I guess you are using an older version.  For better compatibility you can use a different implementation of your `byteToHex()` method thst doesn't need that class.  See for example [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java).

Comment: Well, if it solves your problem you should formally approve my answer.